# I stopped mDNS with " sudo service avahi-daemon stop" but it keeps restarting

Tags: networking, 18.04, services, mdns

I want to stop avahi-daemon (mDNS) and have it stay stopped.

It seems to restart a bit after midnight.  Obviously some sort of periodic job is restarting it but I can't figure out what is.

TANGENT: I tried stopping avahi-daemon.service with systemctl but that did not work.  Only the older style "service  stop" stopped the service (albeit temporarily).

Comment: What exactly happened when you used systemctl? did you try masking the service instead of just stopping it (`sudo systemctl mask --now avahi-daemon.service`)?

Answer (score 3):

You need to stop socket. You can use this command:

```
sudo systemctl stop avahi-daemon.socket avahi-daemon.service
```

Also you can disable service forever and restart the system:

```
sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon.service
reboot
```

To revert it run:

```
sudo systemctl enable avahi-daemon.service
```